# Python 3.6, I have vcvarsall.bat, however I'm still getting the error that it can't be found

Tags: python-3.x

Essentially just what the title says. I have everything set up to allow me to install python modules, but the computer insists that vcvarsall.bat isn't installed. Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to do in the first place? where is your exact error message?

Comment: [How to deal with the pain of “unable to find vcvarsall.bat”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/)